# Fetch multi-row, single-column array using Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, doctrine, doctrine-query

I have a Doctrine fetch statement like this

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM table LIMIT 2";
$result = $db->fetchAll($query);
```

which returns the array like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
    )
)
```

Since the only column I fetch is ID, I don't need the array scope do be that deep. Is there a convenient way of making Doctrine return the results in a "flat" array, similar to what what PDO does:

```
$result = $db->query($query)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

will return

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
```

Currently I am flattening it using

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', array_map("array_values", $result));
```

Comment: Whilst not the most elegant way of doing things, the call_user_func_array DOES work as expected and flattens a single getArrayResult correctly, if only one column is present

Answer (score 15):

You can simply use the PDO functionality (at least if you have MySQL).

```
$ids = $db
    ->executeQuery($query)
    ->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)
;
```

Answer (score 6):

To resolve this problem you have to make your custom doctrine hydrator.

1. First: Make your own hydrator

```
<?php
namespace MyProject\Hydrators;

use Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\AbstractHydrator;

class CustomHydrator extends AbstractHydrator
{
    protected function _hydrateAll()
    {
        return $this->_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    }
}
```

2. Add your hydrator to Doctrine configuration file :

```
<?php
$em->getConfiguration()->addCustomHydrationMode('CustomHydrator','MyProject\Hydrators\CustomHydrator');
```

3. Finaly you can use your cutom hidrator :

```
<?php
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM CmsUser u');
$results = $query->getResult('CustomHydrator');
```

Comment: I need to do the same thing and I was hoping someone had already published their custom hydrator, but I can't seem to find any. Did either of you complete this task?

Comment: Found it: https://www.techpunch.co.uk/development/create-custom-doctrine2-hydrator-symfony2

Answer (score 1):

I found a method called `fetchFirstColumn` which appears to do this. This was probably added in a later version of doctrine. I am currently on Doctrine ORM 2.7.4.

I am using it like this in Symfony:

```
$statement = $connection->prepare('SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = :baz');
$statement->execute([':baz' => 1]);
$result = $statement->fetchFirstColumn();
```

The value of $result will be a numerically indexed array starting at 0 like this:

```
[
    0 => 'foo1', 
    1 => 'foo2'
];
```

Answer (score -1):

Fetch the data using fetchAssoc:

```php
$result = $db->query($query)->fetchAssoc(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

You will get an Array like this:

```
Array ( 
    [id] => 11
)
```